# ng-drag events not triggered

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<div ng-drag="true" ng-drag-start="onDragStart($data, $event)">
      Draggable 
</div>
```

The div is now draggable but none of the drag events are being fired i.e

```
ng-drag-start or ng-drag-move  or ng-drag-stop or ng-drag-success
```

I do not have a drop area as I want the div to go back to its original position where it was dragged from.

What could be the reason? How do I fix this?

Comment: please create a fiddle or other example to show your problem

Comment: I was not able to add ngDraggable.js to the fiddle.however, there is nothing fancy in my project that might interfere. Just the html div and function being called.

Comment: well, which *draggable* plugin are you using? there are multiple...

Comment: I am using ngDraggable. https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable @DonJuwe

Comment: please create a fiddle by importing the sources and your code

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your draggable items in a `ng-drop`, Then you'll have access to the events like `ng-drag-start` and `ng-drag-move`

```
<div ng-drop="true" ng-drag-start="onDragStart();">
    <div ng-drag="true">
          Draggable 
    </div>
</div>
```